# Cookie handling in react and expressjs

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, jwt

I'm trying to send cookie from the server to the react app and use this cookie as auth in the middleware. With the postman, everything is working, but in the browser, it is not.

As I have read some tutorials I need to set up cors and here is the snippet of my server-side app.

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000/", credentials: true }));
res.status(200).cookie("login_auth", token, { httpOnly: true, domain: "http://localhost:3000" }).json({ user });
```

Then I'm sending the post request

```
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/user/login", { email, password }, { withCredentials: true })
```

but when I check the cookie storage for my app there is no cookie and further, I have no idea how to send the cookie back to the server to fulfill the middleware. In postman it is all done so easily.

I can save the cookie with the "js-cookie", but I don't think it is the right way to do it.

```
Cookies.set("login_auth", response.data.token);
```

Somebody help?

Comment: How are you checking cookie storage? Note that cookie wouldn't be visible from React or other JS code because you set it to HTTP only.

Comment: via chrome dev tools, I mean the cookies storage in the application tab

Comment: I got it, it was a matter of the proxy set up.